# Displaying a drop-down PopupWindow when a ListView item is clicked, then scrolling the ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

When the PopupWindow is displayed and the ListView is scrolled, so that the anchoring item is out of the window, the View of that item gets recycled by the Adapter. Then the PopupWindow starts jumping around the screen because it doesn't know where's its original anchor located.

Is there a correct way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

1. A grandparent of the anchor view is the view returned by `Adapter.getView()`. Upon showing a `PopupWindow` as drop-down, store a flag in the grandparent's tag. Also store a reference to this gandparent, and the selected item id.
2. In `Adapter.getView()`, when the requested item id equals the selected item id, use `PopupWindow.update()` to attach the popup to the new view. Remove the tag from the old grandparent and update the grandparent reference.
3. In `Adapter.getView()` if you get a `convertView` which has the flagged tag, and the requested item id differs from the selected item id, use `PopupWindow.update()` to un-attach the popup from the grandparent. Set the grandparent to `null`.

This is a bit complicated so I haven't tried it yet, but it should work and I'm writing it here in case someone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I think displaying PopupWindow is not the correct solution.

Anyway if you have that in place already, the list scroll should dismiss the PopupWindow because keeping it dosen't makes sense as you have already scrolled the list.

Comment: What I would like to happen in such case is that the popup sticks to the correct border, and if the item is scrolled back in then the popup is re-anchored to it. This is what actually happens until my item view gets recycled.